# All tests skipped in vs2012

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest, .net-4.5

I had a project in vs2010 and used a testsettings file in order to include intellitrace, code coverage and test impact. After converting to vs2012, everything still worked fine.

However, when I moved the projects in my solution to .net 4.5 from 4.0, visual studio started skipping all of my tests. I messed with the test settings and found that unchecking intellitrace caused the tests to work again.

Does anyone know why intellitrace would cause tests to be skipped with .net 4.5? Is there any way to remedy this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

No idea why, but the same thing happened to me.

I just did a find replace on [TestClass] -> [TestFixture], [TestMethod] -> [Test] and used NUnit instead.

This resolved the issue.